# WSO2 esb validator mediator not showing exact failure

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I configured a WSO2 validator mediator.

```
 <validate cache-schema="true">
        <schema key="gov:/myxsd/Student.xsd"/>

        <on-fail>
```

The mediator is going the on-fail block ; but doesnt display what validation is failing.How can i get the exact cause for the failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the log mediator to log your error or use the 'makefault' mediator with a 'respond'. For example:

```
<on-fail>
   <log category="ERROR" level="custom">
       <property name="message" value="Validation unsuccessful"/>
       <property expression="get-property('MessageID')" name="message_id"/>
       <property expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" name="error_message"/>
   </log>
</on-fail>
```